# Named range does not return correct amount of cells

Tags: vba, excel

So I have a column filled with names from `B5:B28`. Looking up dynamic named ranges, I used the following formula to get the list of names in the said column:

```
=OFFSET(Overview!$B$5, 0, 0, COUNTA(Overview!$B$5:$B28),1)
```

Note that the only rows populated in column B are `B2` until `B28`, with `B5` being the starting point of the list of names. The `$B28` in the formula above constantly changes even if there is absolutely nothing on the rows below `B28`. And that's where the problem lies.

All rows from `B5:B28` are populated with literal strings (no formulas) and do not have a blank cell. When I get the value of `Range("Names").Rows.Count`, it only returns 21, 3 rows short. I understand that the range is meant to be fluid but I don't understand why the `COUNTA` is getting a lesser amount.

Checking `=COUNTA(Overview!$B$5:$B28)`, it outputs the correct value of 24. Can someone explain to me what is happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "The $B28 in the formula above constantly changes" ?

Comment: When you defined the range "Names" to be `$B$5:$B28` were you in a cell on row 4?  If so the range, when referred to in VBA (implicitly from cell A1) will be only from `$B$5:$B25` and thus only 21 rows in size.  I can't understand why a formula in Excel (which is from a non-A1 cell) would be thinking the size was anything other than 24 rows if the formula in that cell referred to `$B$5:$B28`.  (Obviously, if it referred to `Names`, rather than `$B$5:$B28`, it would be reduced or extended depending on which row the formula was placed.)

Comment: @YowE3K I've posted an answer referencing your comment plus a better form of the formula.  If you would prefer to answer yourself, ping me and I'll remove it

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I'm more than happy to let your answer stand :)

Comment: You have defined a relative name - so the cells referred to by the formula depend on the location of the formula containing the name. If you want to use relative names I recommend switching to R1C1 mode and looking at the refers-to formula of the name - then its much clearer what the Name is going to do.

Comment: @TimWilliams Whenever I check the Name Manager, the end range value in the `COUNTA` function changes.

Comment: @YowE3K I was expecting that the values of the Names range would be the ones in the specified range ($B$5:$B28). And no, I was on B5 when I defined the Names range.

Comment: Because you have specified an absolute start point but a relative end point, things get very confusing.  Assuming you had values in every cell in the range B5:B40 (I realise you don't, but let's assume you do), then setting a named range referring to $B$5:$B28 (set up while on row 5) will mean that a formula such as `=COUNTA(Names)` in cell C5 will return 24 (referring to B$5:B28), the same formula in cell C6 will return 25 (referring to B$5:B29), in C7 will return 26 (referring to B$5:B30), ...,, in C18 will return 37 (referring to B$5:B41), in C19 will return 37 (referring to B$5:B42).

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the point of using the OFFSET range is to define a variable count of rows that are dependent on the height specified by COUNTA? ie if I my initial COUNTA range was from B5:B28 and all cells in there had values, the height would be 23 which would start from B5. Or am I getting this wrong?

Answer (score 2):

YowE3K's comment tells you the why, reproduced here for completeness

> When you defined the range "Names" to be $B$5:$B28 were you in a cell on row 4? If so the range, when referred to in VBA (implicitly from cell A1) will be only from $B$5:$B25 and thus only 21 rows in size. I can't understand why a formula in Excel (which is from a non-A1 cell) would be thinking the size was anything other than 24 rows if the formula in that cell referred to $B$5:$B28. (Obviously, if it referred to Names, rather than $B$5:$B28, it would be reduced or extended depending on which row the formula was placed.)

A better way to form the formula is (assuming `B2`, `B3`, `B4` are *always* populated)

```
=OFFSET(Overview!$B$1, 4, 0, COUNTA(Overview!$B:$B)-3,1)
```

Comment: The data exists on cell `B5` and can extend to how many entries the user inserts though

Comment: That's why I used B:B.  Did you try it?

Comment: The revised formula could still offset from $B$5, and the `-3` could be replaced with a count of cells in B1:B4, i.e. `=OFFSET(Overview!$B$5, 0, 0, COUNTA(Overview!$B:$B)-COUNTA(Overview!$B$1:$B$4),1)`.  (Whether it is an offset from B1 or B5 is not really very important, although it is probably a bit more transparent using B5, but the use of another COUNTA to get rid of headers will probably make the code a bit more foolproof.)